# Unable to Click and Call PhoneNumber in iOS using React Native WebView

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, webview

Hi I'm using React Native WebView Library https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview and unable to detect phoneNumber using dataDetectorTypes={['phoneNumber']}

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#datadetectortypes

or How can I pass a URL from React Native JS to Swift to implement Native iOS WebView?

```
<WebView
                        // key={refresh}                                               
                        source={renderedOnce ? {uri: url} : reload}
                        // originWhitelist={['*']}
                        // style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 1}}
                        // scalesPageToFit={true}
                        // javaScriptEnabled={true}
                        // domStorageEnabled={true}                                               
                        dataDetectorTypes={['phoneNumber']}
                        useWebKit={true}
                    />
```